# Can we order custom made Raspberry PI?

Tags: hardware

I may need a modified version of Raspberry PI.
For example I do not need the HDMI out or the video out no USBS add a 3G modem...

Is this feasible and what may be the cost of such a change.

The second part of the question:
Do I have the right to use the modified PI in a standalone product that I can mass produce and sell?

Comment: You can add a 3g modem and just not connect the HDMI (this would be far cheaper than getting a small number of custom boards produced). Knowing what exactly you are trying to accomplish might help us point you in the right direction.

Comment: The Pi Schematics are open source. You can use those to build your own PCB - Organize what you want and where, maybe even dump 1GB RAM or onboard solid state memory if you wanted.You can't use Pi logo though, maybe your own :) Send it off for production in China. If you look around some people can do this from 10 pieces - But its better to go 100's or thousands for best price. Its really easy! I have done it for something else without effort. The worst part is the PCB design.

Answer (score 9):

### Short answer:

*It's impossible*

### Rationale:

#### Technical

Even small change in a production line costs a lot of money. The low cost of RaspberryPi computer comes in big part from the fact that it is produced in such big quantities. Changing the manufacturing process for some small amount of boards would be very expensive.

### Political

RaspberryPi foundation is not commercial company and their goal is not to sell hardware. So even if you had enough money to cover the cost of manufacturing process change, I don't think the foundation is interested in providing such a service.

### Longer answer:

It is possible to build RaspberryPi yourself since hardware documentation is available for download. You would have to change the design to suit your needs and find some factory that will create the devices for you. But there is a big problem - some of the parts (like the most important one - the SoC) that are needed can not be easily purchased unless you buy them in really big quantities.

Comment: I am aware that it's very old post but using such strong words like impossible should always be avoided specially when you talk about technology. Element14 started [custom Pi services](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76955?forceNoRedirect=true).

Comment: I'd love to have a custom Pi: strip off the audio, micro USB power, camera and display connectors. Add SATA port and SATA style power plug. Sadly, unless at least 10,000 other people feel the same way, the cost of changing the design won't be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Although the pi has been enormously successful in terms of volume - the Foundation originally planned on about 10k units, so somewhere around that volume you probably could design your own.

The processor on the pi was cost optimised and isn't really that great, but it does have a nifty GPU built in that you don't seem to care about (so why pay for that?).

I don't think you'll be able to get the CPU/data sheets from Broadcom for just 10k units. The Foundation has some members that work for Broadcom and managed to get a great deal on the processors.

Part of the attraction of the pi is that apart from a couple of minor variations - everyone is running the exact same hardware so it's easier for people who aren't experts to get help from people who are.

So you want an ARM CPU with a bunch of RAM - some GPIO and 3G (probably via USB)? If your volumes are high enough you can probably make something around the same price of the pi, but the pi would be a crappy starting point.

I'd have a look at the open source [Beagle Bone Black](http://beagleboard.org/products/beaglebone%20black) instead

Answer (score 2):

Im pretty sure, that there is no law that prohibits using one product as part of your product. You can use some components available on market to manufacture something.

You can't use Raspbery Pi logo and name on your product without a license from Raspberry Pi Foundation.

You **have to** read carefully [Raspberry Pi trademark rules](http://www.raspberrypi.org/trademark-rules/).

Answer (score 0):

I used these guys. 
[www.customrpi.com](http://customrpi.com).

I have a pretty complex board with Power over Ethernet, NFC, Touch screen over LVDS and USB, Audio and Mic over USB, Wifi, Bluetooth..., and it all worked out.

They use the raspberry pi compute module and make a motherboard for it. It's amazing how you can cramp components even under the compute module itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Geppetto](https://www.gumstix.com/geppetto/?utm_source=customerSuccess&utm_medium=demandgeneration&utm_campaign=cold&gsaffiliate=rupin) to build out your board. You'd essentially design a board that has a Pi connector, and plug the Pi into the board. Useful if you want to develop very specific requirements and are on a short timeline.